# protecting javascript code by placing in php code

Tags: javascript, hidden

I was wondering, when trying to protect javascript code, instead of just obfuscating it and making all measures of dynamically loading it, couldn't you just run the code through a .php file to make it hidden in the html source code?

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't work that way - javascript code MUST be visible to client browser because browser parse and runs it + there is no way to "hide" it under .php file.

With php file you can send/generate javascript code to the browser - just as you do with regular html

Answer (score 0):

No. In order to execute your JS, the client *must* be able to "see" the script.

You could take all sorts of measures to "hide" your JavaScript from prying eyes, such as deleting dom nodes, obfuscating your code down to the property names, etc. Ultimately, this is a fruitless endeavor.

Since the script "becomes visible" and runs on the client-side at *some* point, with enough Developer Tools hacking your scripts *can* be seen. (And with enough reverse-engineering, your obfuscated code *could* be used by others.)

If you want to protect your work, simply place a copyright notice at the top. In Google Closure Compiler, you can preserve a notice like so:

```
/**
 * @preserve Copyright (c) 2013 Quick Fox.
 */
```

Now, if someone has the nerve to use your [obfuscated] code for their own ends, you can sue them. If they reverse-engineer it... at least you can be content with your "contribution" to the open-source community. ;P